# What makes an integral model of a variety exceptional at a prime?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Suppose we want an integral model of the variety $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Q}}$. Fix a prime $p$, and define
$$
\tilde{X}=\mathrm{Spec}\big(\mathbb{Z}[x]\big)\,\backslash\,\big\{(p,x)\big\}.
$$
Intuitively, the fiber of $\tilde{X}$ over $p$ looks different from all the other fibers. But I am having difficulty making this precise, as the variety $\tilde{X}$ is flat over $\mathbb{Z}$, and is even smooth.

> In what way(s) can one formalize the idea that the integral model $\tilde{X}$ is "exceptional" at the prime $p$?

Comment: If you instead work with the projective space over $\mathbb{Z}$ with this point removed, then you will find that the fiber over $p$ is the only fiber which is not proper.